# Define a second elliptical cylinder such that the curve r is the cross section of both cylinders.

Tags: calculus, vectors, contest-math, education, parametric

Hello could somebody help me to solve this problem, I'm really struggling.

let $\textbf{r}(t)=\dfrac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt2}\textbf{i}+\cos(t)\textbf{j}+\dfrac{\sin(t)}{\sqrt{2}}\textbf{k}$

$\text{with }0 \leq t \leq 2\pi\text{  and  }2x^2+y^2=1$

Define a second elliptical cylinder such that the curve **r** is the cross section of both cylinders.

So I know how to get from two planes to a curve that represents the intersection, but somehow I can't figure out how to do this problem.

If someone knows the answer and would like to share it, it would be very much appreciated:)

Thank you very much.

Comment: I think the second elliptical cylinder should be $y^2 + 2 z^2 = 1$

Comment: @GeometryLover how did you come to your answer if I might ask?

Comment: @GeometryLover I think you might be right because if you set your equation equal to the first equation you get x = z, but how did you get your equation in the first place

Comment: The cylinder that you have which is $2 x^2 + y^2 = 1$ relates the $x$ and $y$ components of $r$ such that points of $r$ always lie on it.  By the same token, you can eliminate $x$ (i.e. ignore $x$) and concentrate on $y$ and $z$.  From the trigonometric identity on $y$ and $z$ components you can relate them by $y^2 + 2 z^2 = 1$ just as the first cylinder relates $x$ and $y$ by $ 2 x^2 + y^2 = 1$ in exactly the same way.

Comment: @GeometryLover Thanks for your answer I checked it with geogebra and your answer is correct, but I'm still strugling to understand how you got to your answer. Is it possible you could explain it to me once again

Comment: The $x$ and $y$ coordinates of $r$ belong to the cylinder $2x^2 + y^2 = 1$ while the $y$ and $z$ coordinates of $r$ belong to the cylinder $y^2 + 2z^2 = 1$.  This follows from the fact that $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1 $